# No-nonsense no-signup video chat web app

Tags: webapp-rec

Today I had to do a quick video chat with someone, but he didn't have Skype and was computer illiterate. It was very frustrating to guide him in installing Skype.

Here's what I want: A website we can both go into, and be able to video chat with each other.

I don't want to sign up for an account there, put my email in, or have to do anything else except go in, enter a private video session with my friend (could identify by entering a secret shared token) and then having the chat. I want it to be really simple so a computer illiterate person could do it.

Is there any service like that?

Comment: You could try:=
www.webcamnow.com/

Comment: try signalrtc.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try ubiqq: http://www.ubiqq.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try red5chat demo website:

http://www.red5chat.com/red5chat-flex-edition/index.php

you do not need account, find your friend in list and start private chat

Comment: It's too public-oriented. I want something that's oriented only at private chats. (Remember, my friend is computer illiterate. I don't want to risk suddenly putting him in a video chat with a troop of garden-variety perverts.)

Answer (score 0):

Use Video Char Rounds. You simply access it through facebook and you share a screen so you can surf the net with whoever you are chatting with, or you can simply chat :)

http://apps.facebook.com/chatrounds/?fb_source=search&ref=ts